# To simplify the Linq syntax for group, order and select top 1

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have several data in Deal class like the following one:

```
public class Deal
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public int SiteEdition {get;set;}
 public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

I tried to group them by "Id" and "SiteEdition"; in each group, order by Date, and select top 1 data.
  My code is like:

```
    List<Deal> dealList = new List<Deal>();
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=123, SiteEdition =1, Date = new DateTime(2017,6,1) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=123, SiteEdition =1 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,5) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=123, SiteEdition =2 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,9) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=445, SiteEdition =1 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,14) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=445, SiteEdition =1 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,19) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=445, SiteEdition =2 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,22) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=445, SiteEdition =2 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,25) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=445, SiteEdition =3 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,27) });
    dealList.Add(new Deal(){Id=445, SiteEdition =3 , Date = new DateTime(2017,6,29) });



    List<Deal> finalList = dealList.GroupBy(s=>new{s.Id,s.SiteEdition}).Select(y => new Deal{Id=y.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Date).First().Id, SiteEdition = y.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Date).First().SiteEdition, Date = y.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Date).First().Date}).ToList();
    foreach(var item in finalList)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Id: " + item.Id + "; SiteEdition: " + item.SiteEdition + " ;DateTime: " + item.Date);
    }
```

It works fine but the linq syntax looks ugly, especially the parts of "y.OrderByDescending(m=>m.Date).First()"....

Is there any way to simplify this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't neet to create new instance of `Deal`. Just return one which you already have in the group.

You can use the fact that [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx) preserves the order of the source sequence within the group - simply sort sequence only once and select first item from each group

```
dealList.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date)
        .GroupBy(d => new { d.Id, d.SiteEdition })
        .Select(g => g.First())
        .ToList()
```

Or you can sort each group separately

```
dealList.GroupBy(d => new { d.Id, d.SiteEdition })
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date).First())
        .ToList()
```